# Python Pandas groupby assignment of object dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, merge, grouping

This python `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [3553102778, 3553102958, 3553103948, 3553103948, 3553104038, 3553104038, 3553104128, 3553104218, 3557580098], 'Based on': ['CTR', 'CTR', 'Conv rate', 'CTR', 'Conv rate', 'CTR', 'CTR', 'CTR', 'CTR']}, columns=['ID', 'Based on'])
```

Produces a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
           ID   Based on
0  3553102778        CTR
1  3553102958        CTR
2  3553103948  Conv rate
3  3553103948        CTR
4  3553104038  Conv rate
5  3553104038        CTR
6  3553104128        CTR
7  3553104218        CTR
8  3557580098        CTR
```

Notice how `ID` `3553103948` and `3553104038` have both `Conv rate` and `CTR`?

How do I group this by `ID` but also assign `Based on` the value of `Conv rate, CTR` to get this?

```
           ID        Based on
0  3553102778             CTR
1  3553102958             CTR
2  3553103948  Conv rate, CTR
4  3553104038  Conv rate, CTR
6  3553104128             CTR
7  3553104218             CTR
8  3557580098             CTR
```

I think it's some kind of `groupby` and assignment one-liner but I don't know how to detect if other `ID`s exist outside the row that are equal to the current row's `ID`.

Maybe a `groupby` in conjunction with `apply`?  I'm not familiar with `apply` yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use apply on the groups, which allows you to transform a group.  This means that the function inside returns something for each set of entries that has the same ID.

[group apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply)

`g = df.groupby("ID")
s = g["Based on"].apply(lambda group: group.values)
s.to_frame()`

s is a series, and you may want to convert to a dataframe

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the tip!